# Logs thread in C

Tags: c, multithreading, logging, buffer

Here is my problem ! I want to make a log Thread. But the buffer between the writer thread and the reader thread don't seems to work.

The buffer is in the:

```
typedef struct{
   char *bufLog;
   pthread_mutex_t mutex;
} sLog;

sLog* globalLog;
```

The reader thread read permanently the buffer and print what is it inside on the screen.

```
void* lireLog(void *param_l){ 
    while(1){
        pthread_mutex_lock(&(globalLog->mutex));

        if(strlen(globalLog->bufLog) > 0)
            printf("Log: %s\n", globalLog->bufLog);

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&globalLog->mutex);
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

And the writer thread write into the buffer.

```
void *otherThread(){
   while(1){
     ecrireLog("salut");
   }
}

void* ecrireLog(char *text){ 
    pthread_mutex_lock(&(globalLog->mutex));

    memcpy(globalLog->bufLog, text, strlen(text));

    pthread_mutex_unlock(&(globalLog->mutex));
    return 0; 
}
```

And there is the main()

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

   globalLog->bufLog = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char*)*255);
   res = pthread_mutex_init(&(globalLog->mutex), NULL);
   if (res) {fprintf(stderr, "create %s", strerror(res));exit(1);}

   //creation du thread log
   res = pthread_create(&log_t, NULL, lireLog, NULL);
   if (res) {fprintf(stderr, "create %s", strerror(res));exit(1);}

   res = pthread_create(&other_t, NULL, otherThread, NULL);
   if (res) {fprintf(stderr, "create %s", strerror(res));exit(1);}

   pthread_join(log_t, NULL);
   pthread_join(other_t, NULL);
}
```

Thanks ! :)

Comment: You just keep loosing your log messages. There is no guarantee your previous message will be read before it is overridden by the next message.

Comment: I understand what you meen but the other thread is just an exemple. The problem is that nothing is never printed on the screen

Comment: You're not null-terminating your logs. You're not `pthread_join`ing your threads, nor otherwise waiting before `return`ing from `main()`, exiting your process.

Comment: You don't wait for your threads to finish - `main()` returns immediately after creating the threads, causing your process to exit.

Comment: Also note that globalLog is not allocated before using

Comment: You're right ! I have forget the pthread_join ! But it doesn't work again :p